# Как массово изменить участки кода в файле?

Tags: php, xml

Имеется файл xml, в котором присутствуют примерно такие участки кода:

```
<specs>
    <spec id="1002">
        <name>test</name>
        <value>test</value>
    </spec>
    <spec id="999">
        <name>test</name>
        <value>test</value>
    </spec>
</specs>
```

Помимо этого, есть и другой код. Можно ли массово подобный код переделать на

```
<specs>
    <spec id="1002">
        <name1002>test</name1002>
        <value1002>test</value1002>
    </spec>
    <spec id="999">
        <name999>test</name999>
        <value999>test</value999>
    </spec>
</specs>
```

Comment: Распарсить файл на составляющие, например, через simplexml_load_file, затем сформировать цикл, который будет генерировать нужные поля, и сохранить все в новом файле. Вроде так.

Comment: а пример цикла можно?

Comment: Вам нужны 2 функции/библиотеки, встроенные в PHP (я же не ошибаюсь, сообщество?): simplexml_load_file и DomDocument. Первая получает данные из xml файла, а вторая формирует его. Изучите их, а потом задавайте более конкретные вопросы, если что-то не получится.

Comment: У меня одного вопрос, зачем? У вас есть хорошо структурированные данные. Легко ищатся через `xpath`. А превратитья в свалку. Если это способ "индексации" то явно не лучший! Не протите данные, не добавляйте в них бизнесс логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По хорошему, конечно, надо парсить DOM ([встроенные функции и классы для этого есть](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php)), но, если сильно припёрло и нет времени ждать, то скорее пиши регулярки!

Найти:

```
"#<spec\s+id=\"(\d+)\"><name>(.+?)</name><value>(.+?)</value></spec>#"
```

Заменить на:

```
"<spec id=\"$1\"><name$1>$2</name><value$1>$3</value></spec>"
```

Проверить можно прямо в консоли в одну строку:

```
php -r 'echo preg_replace("#<spec\s+id=\"(\d+)\"><name>(.+?)</name><value>(.+?)</value></spec>#", "<spec id=\"$1\"><name$1>$2</name><value$1>$3</value></spec>", "<spec id=\"1002\"><name>test</name><value>test</value></spec>") . PHP_EOL;'
```

Вернёт:

```
<spec id="1002"><name1002>test</name><value1002>test</value></spec>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Если файл не велик и полностью убирается в оперативную память, как вариант можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и функцией `preg_replace_callback()`. Прочитать содержимое файла можно при помощи `file_get_contents()`, а записать — `file_put_contents()`.

```
<?php
// str = file_get_contents('specs.xml');
$str = <<<HERE
<specs>
<spec id="1002"><name>test</name><value>test</value></spec>
<spec id="999"><name>test</name><value>test</value></spec>
</specs>
HERE;

$pattern = '|<spec\s+id=["\'](\d+)["\']>\s*<name>(.*?)</name>\s*<value>(.*?)</value></spec>|i';
$str = preg_replace_callback(
  $pattern,
  function ($match) {
    return "<spec id=\"{$match[1]}\">" .
           "<name{$match[1]}>{$match[2]}</name{$match[1]}>" .
           "<value{$match[1]}>{$match[3]}</value{$match[1]}></spec>";
  },
  $str
);

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
echo '</pre>';
// <specs>
// <spec id="1002"><name1002>test</name1002><value1002>test</value1002></spec>
// <spec id="999"><name999>test</name999><value999>test</value999></spec>
// </specs>

// file_put_contents('specs.xml', $str);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.